# Not triggering .focusout() when switching textboxes

Tags: jquery

[image]

As you can deduce by the image I'm making a very simple log-in form.
The div containing this has two event handlers.

```
$("#signInBox").focusin(function(){
    jQuery('#signInBox').fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
});
$("#signInBox").focusout(function(){
    jQuery('#signInBox').fadeTo( "slow", 0.4 );
});
```

The problem I'm having is when I change from email to password or vice versa, this triggers `.focusout()` and `.focusin()`.
How can I make my form not lose focus when changing from one textbox to the next?

Comment: Post your HTML or it's impossible to know I'm afraid!

Comment: Why not `focus` and `blur`?

Comment: ^ there's that, why not use the more common events? Also, it's supposed to trigger those events when the inputs lose and gain focus, why would you want something else, what's the use case ?

Comment: @adeneo what other common events would you recommend? I'm trying to trigger focusout when the whole form loses focus not one element of this form

Comment: So just say so, that's easy -> **https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23651/**

Answer (score 1):

Check if the event's firing element is not part of the form using `.parent().length`; bail if so by `return`ing. See this example for a demonstration:

```js
    $("input").focusin(function(event) {
      if ($(event.target).parent('#form').length > 0) return;

      console.log("Fired in");
    });
    $("input").focusout(function(event) {
      if ($(event.target).parent('#form').length > 0) return;

      console.log("Fired out");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <p>Part of the form - should not fire the console.log() on focusin and focusout</p>
  <input type="text" />
</form>

  <p><b>NOT</b> part of the form - <b>should</b> fire the console.log() on focusin and focusout</p>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Id've never thought of checking for using the event handler.
Although by using this code I get
Fired in Fired out 
simultaniously on every click inside the form

Comment: @EChan42 Not a problem - remember to accept when you can :)